# how to allow locally forwarded port 80 to access port 8080 without allowing 8080 directly from external ip?

Tags: iptables, ufw

I have node.js webapp server running on port 8080 to easily run it without root.  I have port 80 forwarded to 8080 to use it on the standard web port.

Is there a way to block 8080 from external direct access, while allowing access to it through the forwarded port 80 using ufw?

If you need more info, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Here's the iptables I'm using.

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80  -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443
```

Comment: Where have you setup the port forwarding, from 80 to 8080? In your internet router or on the same server that is running the web app?

Comment: same machine... it's a linode cloud server.

Comment: It hosts a node.js app I wrote.  To avoid running it as root, I have a bash script that sets up the iptables to forward two upper ports to 80 and 443, then su's into the apps 'user', and as that user runs forever.js which runs the app, which itself only listens on the upper two ports.

Comment: Could you also share with us the script that you use to setup the port forwarding with iptables?

Comment: Yes.  I appended the code above.